# Login Failed for user [sql server user]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS and have deployed several reports. When I force windows authentication, everything works fine, but when I do this:

[image]

I am getting this error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'.
>   (rsErrorExecutingCommand) Login failed for user 'DWH_Reporting_User'.

I've configured the `DWH_Reporting_User` like this:

[image]

here are the details on `DWH_Reporting_User` for the `ReportServer` database:

[image]

here is the security on the server:

[image]

[image]

when i try to set security for that specific folder:

[image]

i am getting this error msg:

[image]

is there something obviously wrong with the way I've configured things?

Comment: Discussion [moved here.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11948/discussion-between---and-jonh)

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @RobertHarvey if possible can you please revert what you did

Comment: Sorry, there's no undo button. Go to the chat window if you need to see the conversation history.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's gone. the link is broken http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11948/discussion-between---and-jonh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was a series of comments.  I went ahead and put it in the chat as well as an answer.

Go to the security of the server not the database and map the user to that database.

Can you recycle the application pool on the server where reporting services is running? Or reboot the IIS server if possible.

Another thing that comes to mind, when you launch this report it goes into the report server "Portal". Does this user have access to the actual report to view it? Click the details section of this "Portal" and assign this user as a content manager role.

DWH_REPORTING_USER is this an admin account on your domain?

Local admin on the server, so did you grant \COMPUTER_NAME\DWH_Reporting_User rights as a content manager in the roles section? Why dont you use a domain admin account?

So how do you access the actual report - that is your issue.
Do me a favor aprem, write up a stored procedure or sql query in the first tab of reporting services and run it using that user. Meaning in the shared data source it should be using this user DWH_Reporting_user. Test the connection then write a small sql statement to retrieve some data. Run the SQL script from within RS do you see any data?

@Aprem look at the three tabs at the top of rs, its the first tab to define datasets, this is where you can create an SQL query (and run it using the red exclamation mark). – JonH 20 mins ago

i defined a new dataset as "select top 1000 * from mytable", i rebuilt the project, deployed it, and now what do id o? – Артём Царионов 16 mins ago

In the "Shared Datasets" you have a dataset right? Double click on it and go to "Query Designer" it is a button on this form. Click on it and "Execute" the query (red exclamation mark). You dont need to deploy it right now, just do it on a test machine.ago

You specify the user in the datasource section "Shared Data Sources", that account is the account being used to "pull" the data. You really need to experiement with RS some more or read some material on it. This is as basic as it gets.

****Ok aprem do you understand your issue now, the user you are using to get the data has no issues, in addition, it is functioning correctly. Now you have to view the report. To view the report is to view the webpage, and to view a web page means you need to either use "Anon" access or windows authentication. So you need a domain or local WINDOWS account to view the report. This account needs to be setup on the RS portal as a content manager role. ****

You are dealing with two beasts, one is the database (db server) and one is IIS (web server) each serve a specific purpose. The database serves to allow you to pull data while the web server hosts the pages.

The reportserver database is very important, it keeps a listing of all your reports and the meta data associated with your reports in the database. It also stores job ids and subscriptions associated with your reports. Basically it is the backend database for all reporting services stuff like reports, datasets, and datasources. Think of it this way when you create a new "Report Project" you are allowed to create reports, datasets, and datasources. Without the reportserver database how would the system remember your datasets, datasources, and report names? It is the heart of rs.

Answer (score 0):

your data set is not used to connect to the reporting services databse, it is used to connect to the database you are getting the data to display on your report.

Does that user exist on the database the report is accessing?

Comment: thank you this is a great point. yes, it does exist it is pictured above as SalesDWH